# Cannot get a value from EditText

Tags: java, android, firebase

i have a little problem, i have been solved my problem before thanks to Alex Mamo, and now i have another problem.

Here i attach my firebase realtime database screenshoot

[image]

Well at the ima i attach, te Cart should have a child refer to table number, i get a table number from edittext sing getText function, and i send it, to another activity, but, when i send it to another activiy and get it, it seems not getting any value. I try to Log, and it doesn't show anything, try to print too, and the reslut is same. My question is, how i can get a value from edittext in other way?

Here i attach my code fo getText function

DineIn.java

```
 EditText txtTable;
    ArrayList<Menu> menuItems = new ArrayList<Menu>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dine_in);

        txtTable = findViewById(R.id.txtTable);
        String tables = txtTable.getText().toString();
        Log.e("Nomormeja", tables);
```

And this cod is for send it to another activity

DineIn.java (this code is outter from onCreate() method)

```
 class CustomAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity mContext;
        private ArrayList<Menu> mItems;

        public CustomAdaptor(Activity context, ArrayList<Menu> list) {
            mContext = context;
            mItems = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return menuItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.order_items, null);

            TextView menuName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuName);
            TextView menuType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuType);
            TextView menuPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuPrice);
            ImageButton addcart = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

            final String menuNames = menuItems.get(position).getMenuName();
            final String tables = txtTable.getText().toString();
            addcart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Like a Session variable ..it passes the dishName from the row that was clciked
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("shared preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("menuNames",menuNames);
                    editor.putString("tables", tables);
                    editor.commit();
                    startActivity(new Intent(DineIn.this,ProductDetails.class));
                }
            });
```

And this code is to get the value on destination activity

Product.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);

        txtNama = findViewById(R.id.tvNama);
        txtQuantity = findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
        btnMin = findViewById(R.id.btnMin);
        btnPls = findViewById(R.id.btnPls);
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("shared preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        menuName = sharedPreferences.getString("menuNames", "");  // taking dishname from menu when clicked a
        tables = sharedPreferences.getString("tables", "");
        Log.d("meja", tables);
        Log.d("menu", menuName);
```

And i set the vale for child at my Cart entry

```
 if(invalid==false){
                            writeNewEntry(tables, menuName, date, quantity);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void writeNewEntry(String table, String name, String dates, int q){
        Cart entry = new Cart(table, name, dates, q);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child(tables).push().setValue(entry);
    }
```

Thank you so much for every help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not pass content to another activity by SharedPreferences.
try send it through Intent...
Sender:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DineIn.this,ProductDetails.class);
intent.putExtra("tables", tables);
startActivity(intent)
```

Receiver(Activity case):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
tables = intent.getStringExtra("tables", "");
```

Comment: i had try usin intent.putExtra but it same, it still not get a value

Comment: have u try debug and watch value of "tables"(in this case) before "startActivity"

Comment: yes, i try to Log before startActivity but no use

Comment: So you do not have the value in that variable?

Comment: "tables = txtTable.getText().toString();" this code in first line inside OnClick

Comment: so you means, "tables = txtTable.getText().toString();" should be in first line inside addcart.OnClickListener?

Comment: That happens, because you are getting value from txtTable, when its empty and you are not updating it when you click button, in that way...
that line will update "tables" value

Comment: Ohh so when i get a value from txtTable at onCreate method, it still empty, so i should getText at onClick button?

Comment: Yes, or when using the editText value in function, to get most recent

Comment: Ok, i will try it again, i will inform you as soon as possible

Comment: Thank you very much it solved, , and now i have anothr problem, but i want to try it for my self first thank yo very much for the help